# how to pandas strftime %j?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a relatively large data set of weather data for 10 years and I wanna group by day of year to get the 10 years low or high for each and every single day so to use `groupby` I created a column in this way:

```
df['dms'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%j')
```

thing is when I use `dt.strftime('%j')` I get two numbers for the same day which is weird, for instance when I filter only by Dec 31st and I do `value_counts()` I get this:

```
365    363
366     82
Name: dms, dtype: int64
```

on the other hand everything work just fine if I did `dt.strftime('%m-%d)`

```
Dec-31    445
Name: dm, dtype: int64
```

I even did `dt.strftime('%b-%d-%r').value_counts()` and I got the same right filter

```
Dec-31-12:00:00 AM    445
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

what is actually going wrong (or to sound less newbie) what is happening behind the scene in the `%j` case

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider an example with the following data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2016-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2019-12-31', '2020-12-31']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df

    Date
0   2016-12-31
1   2017-12-31
2   2018-12-31
3   2019-12-31
4   2020-12-31
```

In the data above, `2016` and `2020` are leap years with an extra day on February 29th to make up for the fact that an actual year is 365 days and eight hours long (so every fourth year, Leap Year/Leap Day exists, because we take the sum of the extra eight hours from the previous 3 years (3 X 8 = 24), and that is why we have leap day!), so we should expect to return `366` with `%j` for said years when we do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2016-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2019-12-31', '2020-12-31']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%j')
df

    Date        Day
0   2016-12-31  366
1   2017-12-31  365
2   2018-12-31  365
3   2019-12-31  365
4   2020-12-31  366
```

However, when you do `value_counts()`, then it returns:

```
365    3
366    2
Name: Day, dtype: int64
```

This is also expected behavior, so `%j` is working correctly behind the scenes as it is accommodating for Leap Years.

Answer (score 0):

%j returns a day number of year 001-366 (366 for leap year, 365 otherwise). Since your data spans 10 years, 366 would be a valid day for leap year.